# Vba list all excel files in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which is supposed to list all excel files in a folder.

Code:

```
Sub List()

'On Error GoTo Message
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Long
Dim i3 As Long
Dim j2 As Long
Dim name As String
Dim Txt As String
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("M4").value)
i = 18
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.files
'print file path
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6) = objFile.path

'print file path
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 7) = Replace(objFile.name, ".xlsx", "")

'print file removal icon
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 30) = "Remove"

'Add Hyperlink
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 27), Address:=objFile.path, TextToDisplay:="Open Announcement"





'Lookup contact info

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 11).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("G" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$C:$C,MATCH(""" & Left(Range("G" & i).value, 7) & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$B:$B,0)),""""))"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 14).Formula = "=IF(""" & Range("K" & i).value & """ = """","""",IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$D:$D,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("K" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$C:$C,0)),""""))"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 18).Formula = "=IF(""" & Range("K" & i).value & """ = """","""",IFERROR(INDEX(Contacts!$E:$E,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("K" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Contacts!$C:$C,0)),""""))"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 23) = "=IF(K" & i & "="""",""Missing Contact! "","""")&IF(INDEX(Data!L:L,MATCH(G" & i & ",Data!F:F,0))=""TBC"",""Missing Data! "","""")&IF(U" & i & ">=DATE(2017,1,1),"""",""Check Date!"")"

'Delivery Dates
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 21).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$Q:$Q,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Range("G" & i).value & """ & ""*"",Data!$F:$F,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$Q:$Q,MATCH(""*"" & """ & Left(Range("G" & i).value, 7) & """ & ""*"",Data!$F:$F,0)),""""))"


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 25) = "Sync"






i = i + 1

Next objFile

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Calculate

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Exit Sub
Message:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

For some reason, despite there being several excel files in the folder, only one file is being listed.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What's the count of files (objFolder.files.count)?

Comment: @Absinthe it's 20

Comment: @ user7415328 Ok, so far so good. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the loop - what happens exactly, when does it exit?

Answer (score 0):

Start with something simple and then make it more and more complicated. The following works for me, displaying all the files you have in the folder. They are printed in the immediate window (Ctrl+G) in the Visual Basic Editor. From there, you can go further:

```
Option Explicit

Sub List()

    On Error GoTo Message

    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim objFSO          As Object
    Dim objFolder       As Object
    Dim objFile         As Object
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim i2              As Long
    Dim i3              As Long
    Dim j2              As Long
    Dim name            As String
    Dim Txt             As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\TestMe\Arch")

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Debug.Print objFile
    Next objFile

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
Message:

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```